# Mysql query trouble: uploading

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I'm trying for last hour solve this problem. I have a long form and I'm trying to upload info into mysql database. Into table I made. This is the mysql query I'm using:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_temp`(`first_name`, `surname`, `birthday`, `nationality`, `email`, `mobile`, `landline`, `address`, `town`, `post_code`, `country`, `password`, `code_conf`) VALUES ([$f_name],[$s_name],[$bday],[$nationality],[$email],[$mobile],[$landline],[$address],[$town],[$post_code],[$country],[$pass],[$conf_code])");
```

If anyone see any problem why it doesn't work pls let me know. Thank you...

```
$f_name         = $_POST["f_name"];
$s_name         = $_POST["s_name"];
$pass           = $_POST["pass"];
$birthday       = $_POST["bday"];
$nationality    = $_POST["nationality"];
$email          = $_POST["email"];
$mobile         = $_POST["mobile"];
$landline       = $_POST["landline"];
$address        = $_POST["address"];
$town           = $_POST["town"];
$post_code      = $_POST["post_code"];
$country        = $_POST["country"];

$conf_code      = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 1, 70);

include("connect_into_mysql.php");
mysql_select_db("jzperson_edu", $conn);

$res_01 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$count_01 = mysql_num_rows($res_01);

if($count_01==0)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_temp ('first_name','surname','birthday','nationality','email','mobile','landline','address','town','post_code','country','password','code_conf') VALUES ('$f_name','$s_name','$bday','$nationality','$email','$mobile','$landline','$address','$town','$post_code','$country','$pass','$conf_code')");
header("Location: home.php");
}else{echo "This email is already registered. If you lost your password you can reset it here.";}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you sanitizing those variables you put in the database? ps, you can use `{$varname}` or `'.$varname.', not `[$varname]`

Comment: I'll put whole code into question. I'm editing it now.

Comment: What is the exact error message? And please remove the square brackets [ ] and try it again. What error message do you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ You must be aware of SQL injections : please [read this article](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php). Encapsulate all your $_POST data with mysql_real_escape_string, for example :

```
$f_name         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["f_name"]);
```

2/ MySQL will be deprecated soon, see the red box [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

3/ After all your headers, put a die() (else, execution of your code continues until the end and if client's brwoser redirection is disabled, he may see some unauthorized content).

4/ Do not write very long request in a single line, this may avoid troubles and make the job easier. And to debug it, add a "`or die(mysql_error())` at the end" which will display a message helping you alot to get the solution.

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO users_temp (
    'first_name','surname','birthday',
    'nationality','email','mobile',
    'landline','address','town',
    'post_code','country','password',
    'code_conf'
) VALUES (
    '$f_name','$s_name','$bday',
    '$nationality','$email','$mobile',
    '$landline','$address','$town',
    '$post_code','$country','$pass',
    '$conf_code'
)
") or die(mysql_error());
```

By the way, you are making a check in the user table and you insert into the user_tmp table. You may have conflicts trouble in such a way, nope?